# Navigation LeftBarButtonItem is not rendering properly , frame doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS-CCd4xmRY) tutorial.. 
Title view is working fine. Left bar item is not looking good. I have no idea why.

[image]

Here is my code..

```
 func setUpNavigationBarItems(){
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zS-CCd4xmRY
    let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_nav_app_icon"))
    titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

    let addButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let addImage = UIImage(named: "ic_nav_add")
    addButton.setImage(addImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: addButton)
}
```

Comment: change this line ` addButton.setImage(addImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)` with this `addButton.setBackgroundImage(addImage, for: .normal)` and tell me the result

Comment: @mohsen, the same bro.

Comment: change UIButton to UIBarButtonItem ( for define addButton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame you are setting is being overruled by Auto Layout.

The same is probably true for the title view. If you take a look at its frame at runtime, it is likely not of size h34 w34. It just appears to be because you set titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit, which will make the image fit inside its frame without stretching it.

The left button on the other hand appears distorted because you add the image to a UIButton which uses a UIImageView with contentMode = .scaleAspectFill to display the image (you can see this for yourself by using the view debugger and inspecting the navigation items).

To fix this, I suggest using Auto Layout to specify the size of the items in terms of constraints:

```
func setUpNavigationBarItems(){
    let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_nav_app_icon"))
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 34).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleImageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 34).isActive = true
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView

    let addButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let addImage = UIImage(named: "ic_nav_add")
    addButton.setImage(addImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 30).isActive = true
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: addButton)
}
```

Comment: But I got another problem.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967202/navigationitem-titleview-cant-render-at-the-center-when-there-are-more-than-one